# Symfony5 too many redirect

Tags: symfony5

I just hosted my symfony 5 website, but a page is showing a "too many redirects error".

This page works perfectly in localhost.
I tried to clean my browsing data, but it doesn't change anything.

here is my routes.yaml:

```
homepage:
  path: /
  controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController::urlRedirectAction
  defaults:
    path: /home
    permanent: true
```

here is the result of "symfony console debug:router" command (not sure if it can help):

```
-------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------- 
Name                       Method   Scheme   Host   Path                               
-------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------- 
_preview_error             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}           
_wdt                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}                      
_profiler_home             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/                        
_profiler_search           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search                  
_profiler_search_bar       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar              
_profiler_phpinfo          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo                 
_profiler_search_results   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results  
_profiler_open_file        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open                    
_profiler                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}                 
_profiler_router           ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router          
_profiler_exception        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception       
_profiler_exception_css    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css   
contact                    ANY      ANY      ANY    /contact                           
curriculum_vitae           ANY      ANY      ANY    /curriculum/vitae                  
home                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /home                              
projects                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /projects                          
homepage                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /
```

and here is the called controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

class ProjectsController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/projects", name="projects")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // Load projects information
        $projects = Yaml::parseFile('projects/projects.yaml');
        return $this->render('projects/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'ProjectsController',
            'data'        => $projects
        ]);
    }
}
```

You will probably need some things more, so do not hesitate to tell me ...

Any help or idea will be appreciated :)

Best regards,
hbonnavaud.

Comment: you should check which redirects actually happen. I've experienced apache adding trailing slashes and symfony removing trailing slashes, effectively creating an infinite loop.

Comment: Hi and thank you for this help, but first, how do I check wich redirect is it ? If i set the .env file as "dev" insthead of "prod", i should have the symfony helper, but because of the error, I don't have this helper on the page. And what is "trailing slashes" ? How can I add/remove them ? :)

Comment: you can open up your dev tools in the browser (F12 in firefox) and switch to the network tab. when you now open your symfony project, you should see the request flowing in (and should press escape to stop). there you can see the requests happening. trailing slashes are `yourdomain.org/something/` vs `yourdomain.org/something` (notice the last character in the url). apache has some module that adds the slash, symfony by default removes the slash.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the help you gave me. I finally solved it, with renaming the route... Looks wired but I completly delete files for the route /projects, and create two routes "/projets" and "/projects", and only /projets was working. So I put the old content of /projects into /projets and it makes the job ...